# Is this a typo?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, conventions

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

I've been beating my head over this all day, shouldn't this be $$-mg+c_2 v = m \frac{dv}{dt}~?$$

Comment: If it helps then, check Kleppner and Kolenkow section 3.6 page 98 of the second edition

Comment: Please don't link to imgur albums. Use the insert picture tool to embed images to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minus sign is correct. It's a nice illustration of the care that needs to be taken with sign conventions.

Your book is defining the upwards direction to be positive, so the object has a positive velocity if it is moving upwards and a negative velocity if it is moving downwards. The Stokes drag force points in the opposite direction to the velocity, so if the velocity is positive (upwards) the drag force has to be negative (downwards), and *vice versa*. Hence the equation relating the drag to the velocity is:

$$ \mathbf F_\text{drag} = -c_2 \mathbf v $$

for some positive constant $c_2$.

The gravitational force is always downwards so it is always negative. Just to cause more confusion note that your book writes the gravitational force as:

$$ F_\text{grav} = -mg $$

where $g$ is being taken as the positive scalar $g = +9.81~\text{ms}^{-2}$. Strictly speaking we should write:

$$ \mathbf F_\text{grav} = m \mathbf g $$

where $\mathbf g$ is the gravitational acceleration, which is negative since it point downwards.

Comment: Then shouldn't $mg$ be positive?

Comment: @user1070087 I was just extending my answer to discuss the gravitational force when you posted your comment :-)

Comment: Oh ok I see. Thanks for clearing this up! This is why classical mechanics is so hard to understand on your own :(

Comment: @JohnRennie The gravitational force is always downwards ? If you choose y downwards, the gravitational force is upwards, gravitation force is inertia force ?

Comment: The gravitational force **is** always downwards, or at least whenever I drop something it accelerates downwards. This does not depend on your sign convention for the vertical axis.

Comment: So my answer is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you can choose the “y axis” arbitrary, the equation of motion must be the same.
if you applied this rules

- Inertia forces act opposite direction to the acceleration direction
- Drag , friction and spring forces act opposite to the velocity direction
- Gravitation force is “inertia force “
- External forces can act towards or opposite to the y axis.

To obtain the equation of motion take the sum of the forces equal zero, in both cases you obtain the same equation of motion